# How to find C++ implement code in Android SDK

Tags: android

I see some methods in Android call to native function but I can't browse to see its implementation code from Eclipse. Is there any way to find it?

Comment: Well, Android [is open source](https://android.googlesource.com/).

Comment: But how can I find it in sdk?